# Grails - pass String value from controller to view, and use value for logic in JS

Tags: javascript, grails

Using Grails, after passing a model to my view from my controller

```
<g:render template="editor-template" model="[id: asset.key, json: someJson as grails.converters.JSON]"></g:render>
```

I can access it within the JS as I can log it:

```
console.log("ID for editorSetup: ${id}");
```

logs

```
ID for editorSetup: episode1
```

However, the next line trying to do some operation on this, whether its assigning the value to a new variable, or making a method call on it, e.g.

```
var id = ${raw(id as String)}
```

results in a

```
ace:251 Uncaught ReferenceError: episode1 is not defined
    at ace:251
```

What I want, is to be able to use the String literal "episode1" to call another method that does a lookup for the element with this ID. If I try to call the method directly I get the same result as when trying to set a new variable to its value.

I have tried:

- Passing from the controller with `as String`
- Using just `${id}` in the js
- using `.toString()` in the js
- using `.val()` in the js
- using `.valueOf()` in the js

Any other ideas appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but I think you can put the *id* variable into a hidden field on page:

```
<input id="id-field" value="${id}"/>
```

And then retrieve its value in js. It should be treated as literal string.

Comment: I don't think you did understand 100%, but it did give me an idea.

GSP:
<div id="id-field-${id}" data-id="${id}"/>

JS:
var myId = document.getElementById('id-field-${id}').getAttribute('data-id');
console.log("myId: " + myId);
setupEditorForId(myId);

I think there was something weird going on with nested templates etc - so the issue is part of a bigger grails setup. The above gets what I want done. Seems very convoluted and not best practise - will investigate more and see if I can actually see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You have  passed the following model with data,

```
model="[id: asset.key, json: someJson as grails.converters.JSON]
```

You can simply access these data in your javascript as follows,
declare global variables to access these data everywhere in your page as following,

```
var id = "${id}"; // your string value.
var json = ${json}; // this is your json object which you need to parse
```

Now, you access the value of these variables in your JS.